# QGIS --- Create and move point using external python in an offline environment

Tags: qgis, python, api

I'm pretty new to QGIS and GIS.
I have an python application that get periodically position [lat,long,height] updates of several moving objects.

The idea is that the existing application sends the data to QGIs and QGIS prints the objects as a plain circle on the map. In the next loop, QGIS receives a updated set of the objects and moves/reprints them at the given location. 
My Questions are:

- How do I access the API from an external python script?
- Do I have to create a layer for the objects?
- How do I create a layer from an external script?
- How do I send an object to QGIS or print it?
- How do I move/update these obejcts or is it faster to delete and reprint all objects?
- Could QGIS get the object information from a SQLite-DB?

Best Regards,
Sven

Comment: In case you have access to  the [QGIS Python Programming Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/qgis-python-programming-cookbook) you should have a look at Chapter 8: Tracking a GPS. Although I cannot check it out now, I think it is similar to what you are doing.